# Rails Timezone issue when using "beginning_of_week"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timezone

I've been investigating an issue with times appearing incorrectly when converting between UTC and various time zones. I've tracked this down to my use of the "beginning_of_week" method on rails.

Stripping back all the application logic, the core of my issue is:

```
irb(main):018:0> Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Sun, 10 Mar 2013 23:29:09 EDT -04:00
irb(main):019:0> Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').beginning_of_week
=> Mon, 04 Mar 2013 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

As you can see, the beginning of the week is set, but it's changing the offset from "-04:00", to "-05:00" in the process.

Does anyone know a patch or workaround for this? Or will I need to implement my own beginning_of_week logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the full timezone specification in now:

```
Sun, 10 Mar 2013 23:29:09 EDT -04:00
# ------------------------^^^
```

and the beginning of the week:

```
Mon, 04 Mar 2013 00:00:00 EST -05:00
# ------------------------^^^
```

What awful thing happened to the clocks on 2013-03-10? Why the hateful daylight savings time adjustment happened. There's your one hour difference.

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot daylight savings is now so early in the year in the US....living on the other side of the globe, but I still should have realised that!

Comment: @Planty: Always remember that daylight savings time hates all of humanity and wants to make us miserable.